# Do all complete metric spaces have the least upper bound property?

Tags: metric-spaces

Since complete metric spaces are constructed the same way that one would build up $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$, does that suggest that the least upper bound property is similarly inherited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question doesn't make any sense because to talk about a least upper bound you need an order and a general metric space doesn't have one.

Comment: Is there some natural ordering for general metric spaces?

Comment: Or let's say assuming the axiom of choice, does the least upper bound property hold for a complete metric space under the well-ordering guaranteed by the axiom of choice?

Comment: You do realise that a well-ordening on the reals does not coincide with the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$, right? I see no reason why that would be true